# How to get a column (NEW.{{col_name}}) if its name is stored in a variable - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a variable:

```
DECLARE col_name CHAR(255);
```

How can I take column value from `NEW/OLD` if its name is stored in a variable.

```
NEW.{{col_name}}
OLD.{{col_name}}
```

I need to use this in the trigger.

**MySql 5.5.40**

Comment: you can't.. trigger code doesn't support dynamic SQL like that.

Comment: Did you go through - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html It has some examples that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

if there is known scope of possible values (and i belive there is)
one can use 'case'

```
SELECT
    CASE
    when @col_name = 'columnA' then NEW.columnA
    when @col_name = 'columnB' then NEW.columnB
    -- and so on..
    else 'unknown column'
    END AS [NEW_col_value],
    CASE
    when @col_name = 'columnA' then OLD.columnA
    when @col_name = 'columnB' then OLD.columnB
    -- and so on..
    else 'unknown column'
    END AS [OLD_col_value]
FROM
    ...
```

If type of column differs - then cast them to text..